# iPhone can't verify CalDAV account

Tags: iphone, google-calendar, caldav

I am using Google Calendar and I would like to sync it with my iPhone. Usually, the best way to do this is via setting up a CalDAV account which I've been successfully doing for a while.

However, recently, the syncing has ceased to work. So have I subsequently deleted and re-added the account to my iPhone, but I keep on getting an error message, that the CalDAV account cannot be verified.

Does anybody have any suggestions what I can do about this? I'm absolutely certain the all the data I enter is correct.

Comment: Forgot to ask, what version if iOS? Device?

Comment: The latest version

Answer (score 18):

The answers provided helped me resolve my CardDAV verification issue.  Here are the exact steps I took:

1. Sign in to your Google Account at:   https://myaccount.google.com/
2. In the Security (used to be Sign-in & Security) section select:  ‘Signing in to Google’
3. Select ‘App Passwords’
4. From the dropdowns:  Select the app (contacts) and the device (iphone)
5. Follow the instructions in the pop-up to enter the verification code as the password for your google account on your phone.

I have IOS 11.4.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

CardDAV Error with the iPhone is related to the 2 factor authentication.  You need to log into your Google Account - settings and choose signing into google.

Generate an app specific password - this password you utilize on the iPhone and everything should sync.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that [**Google**](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/99358?vid=1-635771796263860612-1750558310) have made the change.

Google may have limits on the use of CalDAV for security reasons. See [CalDAV API Developer's Guide.](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/caldav/v2/guide)

Google has two prefered ways of accessing their calendar service via iOS.

1. [Google's iOS Calendar App](https://itunes.apple.com/app/google-calendar/id909319292)
2. Built in iOS Calendar app via Google account. (See below)

From Google help:

> You can sync Google Calendar with the Calendar app that comes on your
>   iPhone or iPad.
>
> - Open the Settings app on your iPhone or iPad .
> - Touch Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Add account > Google.
> - Enter your email address > Next.
> - Enter your password. If you have iOS 7 or below and you use 2-Step Verification, enter an app password instead of your regular password.
> - Touch Next.
> - Emails, contacts, and calendar events will now sync directly with your Google Account. To sync only your calendar, turn off the other
>     services.
> - Open the Calendar app on your iPhone to see your Google Calendar events.

Answer (score -1):

fixed issue by removing google profile certificate